# Using escape sequences for keys of type string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there I have a hash that I am trying to incorporate into an algorithm that should eventually update a column in one of my models with specific ids. 
In my debugger everything seems fine I am getting the right data.. The only error I think of is that my hash has keys of type string.. Is there a way add escape sequences to these strings so that they dont break my code?

Here is the hash

```
if Rails.env.development?
        loan_sectors = { "Agriculture/Farming" => [8], "Bars/Public Houses" => [1,2,8,9,6], "B&Bs" => [], "Beauty" => [], "Bio Pharma Engineering" => [],
                "Cafes" => [], "Car Sales Industry" => [], "Construction - Commercial" => [127], "Construction - Residential" => [],
                "Consultancy" => [], "Distribution Services" => [],  "Education" => [] , "Engineering"  => [], "Entertainment" => [],
                "Environmental and CleanTech Products and Services" => [] , "Financial Services" => [] , "Garages—Car Repair etc." => [],
                "Health" => [], "Hotels" => [] , "Legal services" => [], "Marketing Services" => [], "Media Services" => [] , "Motor Industry" => [],
                "Manufacturing"  => [],  "Pharmaceuticals" => [], "Recruitment Services" => [], "Restaurants" => [], "Retail Services" => [],
                "Telecoms Industry" => [], "Tourism" => [], "Transport - Import" => [], "Transport - Export" => [],
                "Transport - Internal" => [],"Wholesale" => []}

        loan_sectors.each do |k, v|
          byebug
          sector = LoanSector.where(name: k).first
          v.each do |cid|
            Campaign.find(cid).loan.update_column(:loan_sector_id, sector.id)
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: IMO, if `LoanSector.name` is a string, then having strings as hash's keys is fine. How would you like to escape them?

Comment: Can I write `"Agriculture/Farming".to_sym` ? I think the reason this code is not working is because of the tab spaces in some of the strings?

Comment: Yes, you can even call `symbolize_keys` on your hash, which will transform all keys into symbols. The question is - do you need this? What you earn by doing this?

Comment: I suppose I need to use escape sequences to get rid of all the spaces in my strings then? I ran the code using the to_sym method and it only updated the first sector correctly with the value 8 then the rest did not update

Comment: If the `LoanSector`'s `name` contains spaces, then why would like to escape them in the hash? :) I do not see a point of that.

Comment: because of this `NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177576/discussion-between-mrshemek-and-llanod11).